# Adding CSS code to a WordPress theme and plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I’m a beginner in WordPress
I installed a theme called **Astra** and **elementor** for layout customization and a plugin called **Sticky Menu (or Anything!) on Scroll** to set the header to fixed
The plugin works well and the header is fixed now but when I add a new section using elementor it should at the top of the screen not after the header because it is fixed now I opened inspect and noticed a class called `.sticky-element-placeholder .sticky-element-active`
has the same header height I tried to set its height to 0 but I don’t know where I should insert this CSS code I insert it into the theme additional CSS code section but it doesn’t work!
What should I do please?

Comment: If you have an issue with a plugin or theme, the first thing you should do is to contact the developers and ask them about it.

Comment: Done.
Thank You!